# using videojs and videojs-contrib-hls not able to configur HLS and videojs.tech.hls are not coming using react js

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

using videojs and videojs-contrib-hls not able to configur HLS and videojs.tech.hls are not coming using react js.

```
import videojs from "video.js";
window.videojs = videojs;
import video from 'videojs-contrib-hls';

let player = videojs("really-cool-video",{html5: {
         hls: {
             withCredentials: true,
                 useCueTags:true
         }}});

player.src({
     src: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm",
     type: 'video/webm'
     });

let hls = player.tech({ IWillNotUseThisInPlugins: true }).hls;
```

here hls is undefined is coming.